C++ Run as admin on user login in user context
I have a C++ program that captures the screen using BitBlt and sends it over the network to another computer. Now for this to work, my program needs to be run in the user's session, since functions like BitBlt or the Desktop Duplication Api capture the screen of the current session. Due to the fact that my program has some other functions that require administrator permissions, I am having some problems with it auto starting when a user logs in. This because it needs, as stated before, be run in the user's session.
I have tried using a self-written windows service and CreateProcessAsUser to run my program, however if the user is not an admin than it does not run with those permissions. On logins from users with admin rights, it works like expected. I have also tried to use the Task Scheduler and cached credentials; however, this causes my program to run in the session of the user whose credentials are cached.

use token of self service for run your app

If you managed to start the program in the restricted user context by means of CreateProcessAsUser from a service then the missing step is to request the elevated token, aka linked token like so:
GetTokenInformation(hToken, TokenLinkedToken, (VOID*)&hElevatedToken, sizeof(HANDLE), &dwBytesReturned);

I have tried this, however this then uses the permissions the user has.

Right after I posted my question, I found an old forum post with a solution. Subverting Vista UAC in Both 32 and 64 bit Architectures
DWORD GetWinlogonPIDInSession(DWORD dwSessionId) {
    DWORD dwWinlogonPID = 0;
    PWTS_PROCESS_INFO pProcessInfo = NULL;
    DWORD dwProcessCount = 0;

    if (WTSEnumerateProcesses(WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE, 0, 1, 
        &pProcessInfo, &dwProcessCount)) {
        for (DWORD i = 0; i < dwProcessCount; ++i) {
            if (_wcsicmp(pProcessInfo[i].pProcessName, L"winlogon.exe") == 0 && pProcessInfo[i].SessionId == dwSessionId) {
                dwWinlogonPID = pProcessInfo[i].ProcessId;
                break;
            }
        }
        WTSFreeMemory(pProcessInfo);
    }
    else {
        std::cerr << "WTSEnumerateProcesses failed. Error: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
    }

    return dwWinlogonPID;
}

const wchar_t* exePath = L"Program.exe";
DWORD winlogonPID = GetWinlogonPIDInSession(newSessionId);
if (winlogonPID == 0) {
    return 1;
}

HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION, FALSE, winlogonPID);
if (hProcess == NULL) {
    return 1;
}

// Get access token of winlogon.exe
HANDLE hToken = NULL;
if (!OpenProcessToken(hProcess, TOKEN_DUPLICATE, &hToken)) {
    CloseHandle(hProcess);
    return 1;
}

// Duplicate the token to get a primary token
HANDLE hPrimaryToken = NULL;
if (!DuplicateTokenEx(hToken, MAXIMUM_ALLOWED, NULL, SecurityIdentification, TokenPrimary, &hPrimaryToken)) {
    CloseHandle(hToken);
    CloseHandle(hProcess);
    return 1;
}

// Close handles
CloseHandle(hToken);
CloseHandle(hProcess);

// Start the process in the user's session with elevated privileges
STARTUPINFO si = { sizeof(si) };
si.lpDesktop = L"winsta0\\default"; // Ensure it runs on the interactive desktop
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
if (!CreateProcessAsUser(
    hPrimaryToken,  // User token   
    exePath,    // Path to the executable
    NULL,       // Command line
    NULL,       // Process attributes
    NULL,       // Thread attributes
    FALSE,      // Inherit handles
    CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE | CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT | CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP | CREATE_BREAKAWAY_FROM_JOB,      // Creation flags
    NULL,       // Environment
    NULL,       // Current directory
    &si,        // Startup info
    &pi         // Process information
)) {
    CloseHandle(hPrimaryToken);
}
else {
    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
    CloseHandle(hPrimaryToken);
}


you not need winlogon token

What do I use instead then? Since the token of the session id doesn't always belong to an administrator account, which I do need for my program.

set session id in duplicated self process token

Split your program into two apps. One that needs admin rights, and one that doesn't. Then have one app run the other app and communicate data with each other as needed.
How can I launch an unelevated process from my elevated process and vice versa?
How can I launch an unelevated process from my elevated process, redux
